# What is the original publisher of Terry Goodkind's book Debt of Bones?

Tags: publishing, the-sword-of-truth, terry-goodkind

I would like to know the original publisher of the hardcover book Debt of Bones by Terry Goodkind?  I am trying to find it online and all I can find is Gallancz as a publisher.

Answer (score 6):

Was first published in Legends: Stories By The Masters of Modern Fantasy (1998) according to Wikipidia [Debt of Bones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt_of_Bones).  [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312867875) shows Tor Books as the publisher of the 1st edition of August 25, 1998.  The story was later published as a standalone hardcover book in 2001 and paperback in 2004 (per the Wiki entry).  Amazon shows a Gollanz as the publisher of Debt of Bones hardcover edition with publication date of 12/31/2001.  Alibris also shows Gollanz but just gives publication date as year only (2001).  [Barnes and Noble](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/debt-of-bones-terry-goodkind/1100215009?ean=9780575072565) shows hardcopy issued with publication date of 8/1/2001 (revised edition) by Sterling publishing.  Thought maybe Gollanz bought Sterling or something like that but I can't find any information around that.  Guess the important point is that the first publication was by Tor Books when it was included in the Legends anthology.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I believe my my copy is by Gollanz, I ordered it through Amazon and ended up with the UK edition somehow

Comment: But is yours a first edition? That's really the only one that matters for this question.